# Python: Search particular string in file

Tags: python, file, search

I have text file, that store orders info in following format. I try to search an order by first line of the block, that represent ID and print 7 next lines. But my code checking just the first line or print all line's that contain an input number. Could somebody help me?

```
4735
['Total price: ', 1425.0]
['Type of menu: ', 'BBQ']
['Type of service: ', '     ']
['Amount of customers: ', 25.0]
['Discount: ', '5%', '= RM', 75.0]
['Time: ', '2017-01-08 21:39:19']

3647
['Total price: ', 2000.0]
['Type of menu: ', ' ']
['Type of service: ', 'Tent    ']
['Amount of customers: ', 0]
    .......
```

I use the following code to search in text file.

```
        try:
            f = open('Bills.txt', 'r')
            f.close()
        except IOError:
            absent_input = (raw_input("|----File was not founded----|\n|----Press 'Enter' to continue...----|\n"))
            report_module = ReportModule()
            report_module.show_report()
        Id_input = (raw_input("Enter ID of order\n"))
        with open("Bills.txt", "r") as f:
            searchlines = f.readlines()
        j = len(searchlines) - 1
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
            if Id_input in str(line):  # I also try to check in this way (Id_input == str(line)), but it didn't work
                k = min(i + 7, j)
                for l in searchlines[i:k]: print l,
                print
            else:
                absent_input = (raw_input("|----Order was not founded----|\n|----Press 'Enter' to continue...----|\n"))
                report_module = ReportModule()
                report_module.show_report()
```

Comment: why do you open the file twice, the first open is unnecessary, include your logic in the try block instead.

Comment: as you can see in the `except` block, he checks, whether the file exists. @Bogdan: use https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists or https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile its much more cleaner

Comment: he could still use the except clause. but opening a file twice for a single task is unnecessary.

Comment: Only recently, I got reprimanded for suggesting a simple check instead of letting Python crash & burn because *[catching exceptions is more Pythonic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424875/remove-everything-before-space-using-regular-expression-in-python/41424922?noredirect=1#comment70055730_41424922)*. Can we please make up our minds about that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following code.

```
Id_input = (raw_input("Enter ID of order\n")).strip()
try:
    f = open("Bills.txt", "r")
    print_rows = False
    for idline in f:
        if idline.strip() == Id_input:
           print_rows = True
           continue
        if print_rows:
            if idline.startswith("["): 
                 print idline
            else:
                 break

    if not print_rows:
        absent_input = (raw_input("|----Order was not founded----|\n|----    Press 'Enter' to continue...----|\n"))
        report_module = ReportModule()
        report_module.show_report()
except IOError:
        absent_input = (raw_input("|----File was not founded----|\n|----    Press 'Enter' to continue...----|\n"))
        report_module = ReportModule()
        report_module.show_report()
```

Comment: I got an error, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stripe'`

Comment: my bad, typo!, check it again, str.strip() stripes any white space, so that it will be easy for comparison

Comment: Hmm, this code didn't work, just close a program after I enter ID, but if remove `else` in `if idline.startswith("["):  print idline else:  break` the program will display the total price of finding block and it actually works well. But need to find a way to display the next 6 lines )

Comment: you are right, it has to loop one more time, check it again